# how to add a formgroup(set of form controls) to a control through a function call(angular)?

Tags: angular

Here is my function that is called on ngOnit,

```
createForm() {
        this.createFormService.buildForm(this.createFormService._formBuilder.group({
            title: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
            metaDescription: '',
            singleImageUploadsImageName: '',
            multipleImageUploadsImageName: '',
            unDevelopmentGoals: '',
            mainEditor: '',
            introduction: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(50), Validators.maxLength(124)])],
            ideacategory: '',
            recipe: [''],
            hashtags: '',           
        }));
    }
```

And below here is a function that is called to set group of controls to the recipe control,

```
initRecipeForm() {
         return this.createFormService.formGroup.controls['recipe'] = this.createFormService._formBuilder.group({
            servings: ['', Validators.required],
            cookingtime: [''],
            ingredients: this.createFormService._formBuilder.array([
                this.initIngredients(),
            ])
        });
    }
```

This works fine but is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way of adding control through a function call is to use addControl method,

I altered the initRecipeForm function as below,

```
initRecipeForm() {
        this.createFormService.formGroup.addControl('recipe', this.createFormService._formBuilder.group({
            servings: ['', Validators.required],
            cookingtime: [''],
            ingredients: this.createFormService._formBuilder.array([
                this.initIngredients(),
            ])
        }));        
    }
```